# Java - How Does Comparator Work If Return Value Is Zero?

Tags: java, compare, comparator, abstract

I'm trying to write a tiebreaker method in Java that will return an entry based on a value in a `Comparator`. This is the abstract method:

```java
protected abstract Comparator<Map.Entry<Team, Stats>> getLeagueTableEntryComparator();
```

Now I would like to separate the entries based on points, then goal difference, then goals scored. Here's the override method in a separate class, comparing by the appropriate fields:

```java
@Override
protected Comparator<Map.Entry<Team, Stats>> getLeagueTableEntryComparator() {

    return (Map.Entry<Team, Stats> teamStatsEntryOne, Map.Entry<Team, Stats> teamStatsEntryTwo) -> {

        int compare = Integer.compare(teamStatsEntryOne.getValue().getPoints(),
                teamStatsEntryTwo.getValue().getPoints());

        if (compare == 0) {

            compare = Integer.compare(teamStatsEntryOne.getValue().getTotalGoalDifference(),
                    teamStatsEntryTwo.getValue().getTotalGoalDifference());

            if (compare == 0) {

                compare = Integer.compare(teamStatsEntryOne.getValue().getGoalsFor(),
                        teamStatsEntryTwo.getValue().getGoalsFor());

        }

        return compare;

    };
}
```

However, it's clear that it is possible for `compare` to be zero at the end, even after having compared each field.

My question is this- what is the actual behaviour of the Comparator if `comparator=0` at the end? Will I need to write a number generator at the end to achieve a "true" random 50/50 pick between the two entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the comparator returns 0, the two entries are considered equivalent. It's then up to you to decide what to do with this knowledge - you could randomly choose between the two equivalent elements, or just apply the same treatment to each (e.g., in this usecase, if the two teams are indistinguishable from each other, you could decide to randomly choose between them, declare them as co-champions, or even decide that they should play a tie-breaker game).

Note that you should never introduce a random part in the comparator's code though - this will cause the comparator's behavior to be non-deterministic, and violate the general comparator contract.

Comment: thanks, what would you suggest to be the best way to pick between two entries randomly without overriding the code above?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that happens when comparator returns 0 depends on *how you're using the comparator*.

If you are using the Comparator to sort a list with `Collections.sort` or `List.sort`, comparator returning 0 means that `sort` should leave the items in their original order.

If you want to randomize the order in this scenario, you can use `Collections.shuffle` to reorder the list before sorting it. This guarantees that all "equivalent" items have the same chance of coming out first.

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
Object winner = list.get(0);
```

If instead you have only two items and want to compare them, you can call `compare` directly and break ties in what ever way you want if the result is zero. For example, for a random choice you can use an instance of the `Random` class.

```
int compare = comparator.compare(a, b);
Random rnd = new Random();
if (compare == 0) {
    if (rnd.nextBoolean()) {
        winner = a;
    } else {
        winner = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`compare = 0` mean objects are equal, and it is not necessary to swap them (in sorting)